# Why does the site attempt to track my web browsing?

Tags: discussion

Firefox (64.0) which I always use in private browsing mode and with tracking detection enabled, indicates that `tex.stackexchange.com` makes attempts to track my web browsing.

edit: this happens whenever I view a question.

Why does the site do that?

Background: I consider the software industry a peril to the humanity ethics, and that big data and the tracking industry are evils to the highest degree, and I am astounded by the general indifference to what is going on nowadawys with this move to the so-called "connected" world they are trying to catch us into accepting without revolt.

I do hope TeX could remain immune to the best possible to these satanic trends of our modern age.

Comment: for some context: this post explains what the different tracking things are used for https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263625/237989

Comment: @samcarter good to know these details; as I am of course using AdBlockPlus I could have hoped that not being an ad consumer, my browsing could remain private, but alas, that is too much to ask for nowadays.

Comment: I don't know for sure (using some add blocker myself) but I think there are no adds on tex.se, only on the bigger sites of the network. This makes we wonder if all these trackers are necessary on all sites...

Comment: @samcarter the answer you link to is basically an answer to my question, and  -- to the extent it is still actual -- contains a very interesting piece about "ComScore". Obviously the ethics of this company are questionable (or appear to be so) in the very own views of the Powers, nevertheless they obide to the pressure of the advertising industry and install it on the site. If I was certain all the tracking in question was only to quantify my site visits hence (a priori) ad views, that would be another matter, but as I can't dispel suspicion my browsing at large is sold to tierce parties...

Comment: The stackexchange is worth millions of dollars, it has to run servers, personnel, pay for energy etc. We *users* are here free of charge ... the money has to come from somewhere.

Comment: @Johannes_B is it worth millionth of dollars from the contribution to human knowledge it represents or from the fact that it has a big user-base hence advertising targets (for some of its sites)? did it started being worth millions of dollars? would it really cost millions of dollars to sustain tex.sx activity as a forum of questions and answers?

Comment: Not sure how to answer. Some investment company thingy pumped 50 M Dollars into the network. All this is a big business, to which the users contribute to for free (no pay, but also no charges).

Comment: If you are looking for a non-commercial LaTeX forum -> latex.org (no commercials, no reputation)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model

Comment: @Johannes_B ok, there is a [2017 dated answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300027/344080) which adds a bit of info to all the others (2011)

Comment: @samcarter according to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model/300027#comment785805_79448) ads are toned down for users with > 200 rep but it may be true anyhow that there are no ads on tex.se. This makes my worry about tracking even more pregnant because this and other comments at [the question linked to by Johannes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model) indicates that one must not remain naive about what "advertising" really means (to be cont.)

Comment: @samcarter (cont.) the real, modern, value in advertising is into capturing your behaviour profile and targeting at you tailored ads. In near future, when someone will go to a commercial mall, facial recognition will allow displaying on the corridor walls advertising constructed on the basis of the browsing behaviour of the individual on internet. Are we happy about that future?

Comment: @Johannes_B ok about latex.org; I think I knew about it but was under impression at some point it was primarily a German language forum, obviously I mixed up with something else.

Comment: I was wondering what will appear on the corridor walls if the browsing behavior usually is on adult-only sites :):):)

Comment: You are using Firefox, so all your DNS requests are rerouted via NSA-controlled servers anyway: https://ungleich.ch/en-us/cms/blog/2018/08/04/mozillas-new-dns-resolution-is-dangerous/

Comment: Here are some more nice things about Firefox: https://drewdevault.com/2017/12/16/Firefox-is-on-a-slippery-slope.html, https://twitter.com/NicolasPetton/status/884694176515936256, https://blog.mozilla.org/press-de/2017/10/06/ein-neues-cliqz-experiment-in-firefox/ (only in German).

Comment: @HenriMenke that's too much information for me to digest, I acted on `network.trr.mode` which was `0`, I set it to `5` but this added a bit to my profile at the NSA. The problem with `about:config` is that it is lacking tooltips information of the meaning of the value settings.

Comment: @jfbu I'm sorry to skip back to some previous topics in the comments. You ask whether TeX.SE could be standalone. The answer is: there is many standalone forums about TeX and none of them is as successful as this one. So yes, you could probably now quite SE and even migrate the contents, but you very likely wouldn't have all of that without the whole network. Actually, this option was discussed just months ago with the network graphical redesign being unrolled.

Comment: @HenriMenke (just to thank your for the links, when I said "too much information" I meant simply "much information", and I was very grateful to have my eyes getting opened up on these topics)

Comment: @boycott.se-yo' I am intrigued by "even migrate the contents", is that technically feasible?

Comment: @jfbu I believe yes, both legal (under some conditions) and technically feasible.